# pandas.DataFrame - how to reindex by group?

Tags: python, pandas

Can new index be applied to DF, respectively to grouping made with `groupby`? Precisely - is there an elegant way to do that, and can original DF be changed through `groupby` groups at all?

UPD:
My data looks like this:

```
   A  B         C
0  a  x  0.903343
1  a  z  0.982050
2  g  x  0.274823
3  g  y  0.334491
4  c  z  0.756728
5  f  z  0.697841
6  d  z  0.505845
7  b  z  0.768199
8  b  y  0.743012
9  e  x  0.697212
```

I grouping by columns 'A' and 'B', and I want that every unique pair of values of that columns would have same index value in original DF. Also - original DF can be big, and Im trying to figure how to make such reindex without inefficient forming whole new DF.

Currently Im using this solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [random.choice(ascii_lowercase[:5]) for _ in xrange(10)],
                    'B': [random.choice(['x', 'y']) for _ in xrange(10)],
                    'C': [random.random() for _ in xrange(10)]})

df['id'] = None
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i, (n, g) in enumerate(df.groupby(['A', 'B'])):
    g['id'] = i
    new_df = new_df.append(g)

new_df.set_index('id', inplace=True)
```

Comment: It would be convenient if you supplied some sample data.

Comment: Also, there are a few ambiguities here you could clarify. Do you want the group names modified? The selected row indices within groups? If you could show a starting df, a groupby, and the kind of reindexing you are trying to accomplish that would be helpful.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it appears you are trying to create an integer index with unique values for each combination of columns A and B.  Unless you require the integer index for a specific reason, you can simply create a MultiIndex using columns A and B with `df.set_index(["A", "B"]).sort()` which will allow you to do all of the same selection and slicing the integer index would using `xs` and `ix`.  Example: `df.ix["a"].ix["y"]` or `df.xs(key="x", level=1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quickly with some internal function in pandas:

Create test DataFrame first:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [random.choice(ascii_lowercase[:5]) for _ in xrange(10)],
                    'B': [random.choice(['x', 'y']) for _ in xrange(10)],
                    'C': [random.random() for _ in xrange(10)]})
```

If you want the new id the same order as column A & B:

```
m = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays((df.A, df.B))
df.index = pd.factorize(pd.lib.fast_zip(m.labels), sort=True)[0]
print df
```

The output is:

```
   A  B         C
1  a  y  0.025446
7  e  x  0.541412
6  d  y  0.939149
2  b  x  0.381204
3  c  x  0.216599
4  c  y  0.422117
5  d  x  0.029041
6  d  y  0.221692
1  a  y  0.437888
0  a  x  0.495812
```

If you don't care the order of new id:

```
m = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays((df.A, df.B))
la, lb = m.labels
df.index = pd.factorize(la*len(lb)+lb)[0]
print df
```

The output is:

```
  A  B         C
0  a  y  0.025446
1  e  x  0.541412
2  d  y  0.939149
3  b  x  0.381204
4  c  x  0.216599
5  c  y  0.422117
6  d  x  0.029041
2  d  y  0.221692
0  a  y  0.437888
7  a  x  0.495812
```